# Truffle test javascript

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript

I have a .sol contract:

```
contract HelloWorld {
    string name="TEST";
    uint number;

    function HelloWorld() {

    }

    function getName() returns (string) {
        return name;
    }

    function getNumber() returns (uint) {
        return number;
    }

    function setNumber(uint _number) {
        number = _number;
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to write a test in javascript to call the function setNumber.
My test.js looks like this:

```
var HelloWorld = artifacts.require('./HelloWorld.sol');

contract("HelloWorld:getName", function(accounts) {
  it("should assert true", async function() {
    const contract = await HelloWorld.deployed();
    await contract.setNumber(54);
    await contract.getNumber();
    const result = await contract.getNumber.call();
    assert.isTrue(result === 54);


  });
});
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
Contract: HelloWorld:getName
    1) should assert true
    > No events were emitted


  0 passing (241ms)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: HelloWorld:getName should assert true:
     AssertionError: expected false to be true
```

Can someone help me with the syntax? Or point me in the direction for learning?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: It is better to create a new question if you new issues. Since you removed your original question some answers now appear to be unrelated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The identity (`===`) operator behaves identically to the equality (`==`) operator except no type conversion is done, and the types must be the same to be considered equal.

And since the type of `result` is `BigNumber`, the expression `result === 54` evaluates to `false`.

So you need to change this:

```
assert(result === 54);
```

Either to this:

```
assert(result == 54);
```

Or to this:

```
assert(result.equals(54));
```

Personally I prefer the latter, because I "trust" the implicit conversion inside the `BigNumber.equals` function better than whatever is implemented in the `==` operator (since there are several ways to handle the two arguments passed to `==`, but there is only one plausible way to handle the argument passed to `BigNumber.equals`).

See [here](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/) for all you need to know about `BigNumber`...

Comment: Thanks for your response! I changed it to : assert.equal(result, 54) and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

remove `=` from `await =` . Write it directly `await  contract.setNumber(54)`

Comment: Thanks but I am still getting an error: Contract: HelloWorld:getName
    1) should assert true
    > No events were emitted


  0 passing (164ms)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: HelloWorld:getName should assert true:
     AssertionError: expected false to be true

Comment: what is the value of `result`?

Comment: it should equal 54 but how do I see what the value is?